# Integral calculation question

Tags: real-analysis

Is my following calculation correct? For some smooth $u: \mathbb{R} \to[0,1]$, $$\int\limits_0^1 \big[\chi_{\{u(x)<t\}}(x)\chi_{\{u(y)\geq t\}}(y)+\chi_{\{u(x)\geq t\}}(x)\chi_{\{u(y)<t\}}(y)\big]\mathrm{d}t =|u(x)-u(y)|.$$

Comment: According to my computations, $|u(x)- u(y)|$ should be the correct value of the integral.

Answer (score 1):

The integral can be written in the following way
$$\int_0^1 \chi_{ \{ u(x) <t\le u(y) \}} (x,y) dt + \int_0^1 \chi_{ \{ u(y) <t\le u(x) \}} (x,y) dt$$
If $u(x) < u(y)$, then the second integral is zero, and you get
$$\int_0^1 \chi_{ \{ u(x) <t\le u(y) \}} (x,y) dt = \int_{u(x)}^{u(y)} 1 dt = u(y)-u(x)$$

Similarly, if $u(y) < u(x)$ the first integral is zero and you get $u(x)-u(y)$.